# Converting World coordinates to Screen coordinates in Three.js using Projection

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

There are several excellent stack questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036106/three-js-projector-and-ray-objects), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956442/detect-clicked-object-in-three-js)) about unprojecting in Three.js, that is how to convert (x,y) mouse coordinates in the browser to the (x,y,z) coordinates in Three.js canvas space.  Mostly they follow this pattern:

```
    var elem = renderer.domElement, 
        boundingRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = (event.clientX - boundingRect.left) * (elem.width / boundingRect.width),
        y = (event.clientY - boundingRect.top) * (elem.height / boundingRect.height);

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 
        ( x / WIDTH ) * 2 - 1, 
        - ( y / HEIGHT ) * 2 + 1, 
        0.5 
    );

    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children );
```

I have been attempting to do the reverse - instead of going from "screen to world" space, to go from "world to screen" space. If I know the position of the object in Three.js, how do I determine its position on the screen?

There does not seem to be any published solution to this problem. [Another question about this just showed up on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534000/three-js-converting-3d-position-to-2d-screen-position), but the author claims to have solved the problem with a function that is not working for me. Their solution does not use a projected Ray, and I am pretty sure that since 2D to 3D uses unprojectVector(), that the 3D to 2D solution will require projectVector().

There is also [this issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/899) opened on Github.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks so much for the "screen-to-world" translation pattern. It was a pain for many hours..

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var width = 640, height = 480;
var widthHalf = width / 2, heightHalf = height / 2;

var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
var projector = new THREE.Projector();
projector.projectVector( vector.setFromMatrixPosition( object.matrixWorld ), camera );

vector.x = ( vector.x * widthHalf ) + widthHalf;
vector.y = - ( vector.y * heightHalf ) + heightHalf;
```

Comment: an op on another Stack questions posted this link which also has the solution. Thanks again! https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/78

Comment: getPosition() has been deprecated. Use this instead:
var vector = projector.projectVector(new THREE.Vector3().getPositionFromMatrix(object.matrixWorld), camera);

Comment: I think your code is missing vector before getPositionFromMatrix. So vector.getPositionFromMatrix

Comment: Fixed again. Sorry about that.

Comment: It looks like vector.getPositionFromMatrix() is now called vector.setFromMatrixPosition(). http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Math/Vector3

Comment: @mrdoob this solution not working now :( x: NaN, y: NaN, z: -Infinity always.

Comment: Working fine for me, I'm on r68, @mrdoob any reason why vector is a `THREE.Vector3()` and not a `THREE.Vector2()`? I'm guessing that for screen coordinates we don't need the `z` value but maybe I'm wrong. Also, this answer seems to cover the instance where you want the screen coordinates of a particular object, but what about a specific vector? For example, if I wanted to get the centroid of a face and know the screen coordinates of that, this wouldn't really be useful right? I guess I should ask a new question...

Comment: "object is undefined"

Answer (score 36):

For modern Three.js (r75), a vector can be projected onto the screen with:

```
var width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;
var widthHalf = width / 2, heightHalf = height / 2;

var pos = object.position.clone();
pos.project(camera);
pos.x = ( pos.x * widthHalf ) + widthHalf;
pos.y = - ( pos.y * heightHalf ) + heightHalf;
```

Comment: Note that `object.position` might not be what you need, if the object is part of a group, since `object.position` is the local position within a group.  Using `object.getWorldPosition()` (or `pos.setFromMatrixPosition()`, as in the other answers) instead will account for relative positioning within groups.

Comment: This answer assumes the canvas is the same size as the window. Really one should be using the half canvas width and half canvas height...

Comment: If you want to get the position accurately regardless of the position and size of the containing canvas (which may not be the entire window), you'll want to base these calculations off of `canvas.getBoundingClientRect()` instead of `window`

Answer (score 17):

For everyone getting `deprecated` or `warnings` logs, the accepted answer is for older Three.js versions. Now it's even easier with:

```
let pos = new THREE.Vector3();
pos = pos.setFromMatrixPosition(object.matrixWorld);
pos.project(camera);

let widthHalf = canvasWidth / 2;
let heightHalf = canvasHeight / 2;

pos.x = (pos.x * widthHalf) + widthHalf;
pos.y = - (pos.y * heightHalf) + heightHalf;
pos.z = 0;

console.log(pos);
```

Comment: "object" is not defined

Comment: @JoãoVilaça `object` should the the `THREE.Object3D` instance you are trying to convert to a screen coordinate (it takes the position of that object)

Comment: This is nice, but when the object is behind the camera, `pos.project()` returns a value as if the object is rotated 180 degrees around the camera.

Comment: @Jespertheend do you know any solution on this problem?

Comment: @MarcelEnnix you can check if `pos.z` is between `0` and `1` and assume the object to be off screen when it isn't in this range. Ideally I would have the 2d position approach Infinity when behind the camera but I haven't figured out how to do this yet.

Comment: @Jespertheend Thanks for your answer. I solved it by creating a directionVector from camera to the object and compare it with the lookAt-Vector from the camera. You can see it in action here (browser-mmo): https://g13.ennix.io

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me but they were very close, so I investigated a little bit more and combining some code from those answers plus [this article](https://manu.ninja/webgl-three-js-annotations/#screen-projection) I was able to make it work with the following snippet

```
const vector = new THREE.Vector3();
const canvas = renderer.domElement; // `renderer` is a THREE.WebGLRenderer

obj.updateMatrixWorld();  // `obj´ is a THREE.Object3D
vector.setFromMatrixPosition(obj.matrixWorld);

vector.project(camera); // `camera` is a THREE.PerspectiveCamera

const x = Math.round((0.5 + vector.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
const y = Math.round((0.5 - vector.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));
```