# Projective Z-value of a real-world point in three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, linear-algebra

I want to find the de-normalized projective Z-value for some world point.

I am currently able to get the projective X,Y values by doing what mrdoob shows here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11605007

That example shows how to de-normalize the projective X,Y (taking it from the range [-1, 1] into actual screen coordinates). It does not show how to de-normalize the projective Z. These projective Z values also are in the range of [-1, 1] but I don't know how to de-normalize them.

To frame the question in code, building on mrdoob's answer above:

```
var width = 640, height = 480;
var widthHalf = width / 2, heightHalf = height / 2;

var projector = new THREE.Projector();
// this could be any point; using example from mrdoob's answer
var someWorldPoint = object.matrixWorld.getPosition().clone();
var vector = projector.projectVector(someWorldPoint, camera );

vector.x = ( vector.x * widthHalf ) + widthHalf;
vector.y = - ( vector.y * heightHalf ) + heightHalf;
// what does vector.z represent and how do I de-normalize vector.z?
```

Thanks for your help. If any of my terminology is incorrect or confusing please correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-value is used for depth-sorting. It is not intended to be "de-normalized".

The `near` plane maps to z = -1, and the `far` plane maps to z = 1.

Points inside the frustum will map to a z-value between -1 and 1. (The mapping is not linear, however.)

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Would it be possible to: find a line that is orthogonal to the projection plane and intersects my world point, then find the distance between the two?