# How to Detect collision of Cube Mesh with browser boundary in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

[image]

[image]

I am new in 3D games and ThreeJS. As shown in image above. My Mesh at browser's left boundry and at that time Mesh position is -1035 instead of 0.
It means mesh.position.x in ThreeJS is not Browser window X pixel then what is mesh.position.x in ThreeJS. Is there any calculation to convert Browser Inner Width and Height to as same as mesh.position.x. How to detect collision with browser boundary .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three.js uses a 3D spatial coordinate system where the X and Z axes are horizontal and the Y axis is vertical. The origin (0, 0, 0) is just an arbitrary point in that space, and you can "look around" in the 3D world so the origin might not be on the screen. The coordinates of an object in Three.js-space are also, for all intents and purposes, arbitrary units.

You can convert between the 2D screen space and the 3D world space using [projectors](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Projector.js). Going from 3D to 2D has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586527/converting-world-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates-in-three-js-using-projection), and there is also a nice [tutorial](http://zachberry.com/blog/tracking-3d-objects-in-2d-with-three-js/) on the topic.

So, to find out whether a mesh is on the screen, you should project its 3D position to 2D screen space and then check whether that is outside the size of the window or canvas.