# Three.js Vector.project() gives the value Infinity?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Can anybody make it clear to me why i am getting like {x:Infinity, y:-Infinity, z:-Infinity} from my position values like {x:0.50516157, y:-0.62950189, z:0} when i am trying to project my position vector onto the camera. I have found a similar query [Converting World coordinates to Screen coordinates in Three.js using Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586527/converting-world-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates-in-three-js-using-projection) on this but the solution does not solve my problem. It would be really help full and time saving if someone can help me.

```
var screenvector = new THREE.Vector3();
var position = new THREE.Vector3();
position = convertLatLontoVec3(lat, lng).multiplyScalar(radius);
//convertLatLontoVec3(returns new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);)
screenvector.copy(position);
//till here during debugging i can find the values of position.x, .y, .z 
screenvector.project(camera); //But once this step is executed all the values are becoming infintiy. I don't understand why is it happening.
```

Comment: check `camera.projectionMatrix` and whether `camera.matrixWorld ` is invertible (that is `new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(camera.matrixWorld)`)  we cannot answer you without knowing how your camera is set up

Comment: umm, is this projection or unprojection? Just a wild guess without bothering to open a diagram of the NDC but i think you should be getting infinity if you are behind the camera. A screen vector you probably want to *unproject*

Comment: Thank you for your response, for better understanding here is my code please have a look at it and if there is anything wrong http://pastebin.com/ei7T0mXr

Comment: After some struggle here i got the answer. Before projecting my screenvector onto the camera i have forgot to update my camera.updateMatrixWorld(); and now i have the valid coordinates..

Answer (score 3):

If you are projecting a "screen space" vector, you are most likely right at the camera's origin in *view/worldSpace*, (z==0 in the diagram). Infinity makes sense here. You probably want to **unproject**.

[image: projecting from camera position]

Starting from z==0, anything behind the camera is just infinity (i think).