# ThreeJS Minimum screen width for a single object

Tags: three.js, camera, distance, arcgis-js-api

I am using a very similar project to this example: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/scene-external-renderer-threejs/index.html

This application is displaying a 3D Object (ISS). If you zoom out, the object gets smaller (logical), however I want to have a minimum size for this object. I always want this object to take at least 10 % of the screen width.

How can I achieve this goal?

I don't want to restrict the camera movement by any metods, but I want to enlarge the object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this working you need:

1. Compute bounding Spehre on a geometry of your object using *boundingSphere* ([Geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry))
2. Project bounding spere (example of projection: [Converting World coordinates to Screen coordinates in Three.js using Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586527/converting-world-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates-in-three-js-using-projection))
3. Check if pojected object width is not less than 10% of window width.