# How does A-Frame position the origin of the object placed inside the space?

Tags: aframe

I am following the tutorial of A-Frame to place a box and a sphere into the space. And when i adjust the position, I managed to observe the changes. However, I am not sure, how to determine the origin (on my screen) of the objects I generated. I appreciate if you could assist. Thank You

Comment: Like pixel values on the screen? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36706930/2425787)?