# 3D cube creation and handling events on that cube

Tags: javascript, 3d, paperjs

I have created multiple 3D Cubes in a HTML5 Canvas . 
I was trying to handle a click event on the 3D cube so that i can know which cube got clicked. 
To create the cube I used processingJS. 
It worked well but was not able to get the Click position.
I  read about Paper JS which creates a shape and stores it in a object.
Is it possible to create 3D things with Paper JS. 
Or Is there anyway i can get which cube got clicked through ProcessingJS. 
please share whether there are any other ways to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try three.js.  Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956442/detect-clicked-object-in-three-js

Answer (score 1):

Paper.js deals with 2D *vector* graphics.

While in theory you can represent a cube if you want to, using skewed squares for example, it will take a lot of effort and a lot of time to just create 1 cube.

You are much better of using a 3D library, e.g - [Three.js](http://threejs.org).

Here is an already cooked up example using raycasting to detect the clicks on a side of the cube: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html