# Making an image gallery in a cube using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making my first steps learning to code in javascript and now I'm experimenting with webgl using three.js

The thing is that I am trying to find a starting point to make a cube that will slowly rotates in the x axe.

This cube will have 4 different textures (image and text), and if I click one texture, it would link me to a page or a site.

I find that make an interactive cube is easy. There is a lot of examples in the three.js site but what about make each side of that cube interactive?

Do you have some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of having a box you can have 4 planes facing outwards and each of them will have a material with texture.
2. Each of the planes will have an id
3. There will be a list of what URLs are corresponding to each id
4. Add onclick to the scene(basically it's converting X,Y of mouse to casting rays from camera) [Detect clicked object in THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956442/detect-clicked-object-in-three-js)

You can group them using an Object3D as a parent and then only rotate the parent.