# Object selection checking in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm writing an architecture website using three.js, and need to be able to tell if the user has clicked on a specific plane. Is there a way to do this with a raycaster? If not, is there any other way (please specify, I am new to three.js!)

I have already tried checking if it is equal to the mesh.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
if (INTERSECTED = planemesh) {
  ...
```

}

What is currently happening is it is selecting my plane and I need that to not happen (i.e. they shouldn't be able to delete their workplane)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect clicked object in THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956442/detect-clicked-object-in-three-js)

Comment: `workPlane.visible = false; const intersectedObjects = raycaster.intersectObjects(...); workPlane.visible = true;`?