# three.js raycaster in a container

Tags: three.js, raycasting

for my internship in need to make an aplication with three.js what needs to be in a container on a page but it needs an onclick function on the objects. the problem is i cannot find annything on raycasting only in a container and clicking now will not get objects i need

[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ49c.png)

```
onMouseDown(event) {
    let s = this;

    // calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates
    // (-1 to +1) for both components
    s.mouse.x = ( event.clientX / s.renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    s.mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / s.renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;


    s.intersects = s.raycaster.intersectObjects(s.blocks, true);
    for ( var i = 0; i < s.intersects.length;){

        s.intersects[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
        console.log(i)
        console.log(s.getScene().children)
        console.log(s.intersects)
        console.log("test 123")

    } 
    if (s.intersects == 0){
        console.log(s.mouse.x)
        console.log(s.mouse.y)
    }

}
```

edit: it is not the same as [Detect clicked object in THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956442/detect-clicked-object-in-three-js) he is not working in a container. plus he has a little problem with the margins for me everywhere i click on the screen it does not detect what i need and i need it to be working only on the container not the whole webpage plus there help is outdated and is not working annymore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect clicked object in THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956442/detect-clicked-object-in-three-js)

Comment: did you leave out some of the code? Because it looks like you are not setting up the raycaster with your mouse-coordinates.

Comment: i left out some code yeah i got my main problem fixed but now running into a new problem and that is that the click will not see the object\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with a canvas that is not at the top-left corner of the page, you need one more step to get to the normalized device coordinates. Note that the NDC in WebGL are relative to the canvas drawing-area, not the screen or document (`[-1,-1]` and `[1,1]` are the bottom-left and top-right corners of the canvas).

Ideally, you'd use `ev.offsetX`/`ev.offsetY`, but browser-support for that isn't there yet. Instead, you can do it like this:

```
const {top, left, width, height} = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();

mouse.x = -1 + 2 * (ev.clientX - left) / width;
mouse.y = 1 - 2 * (ev.clientY - top) / height;
```

See here for a working example: https://codepen.io/usefulthink/pen/PVjeJr

Another option is to statically compute the offset-position and size of the canvas on the page and compute the final values based on `ev.pageX`/`ev.pageY`. This has the benefit of being a bit more stable (as it is not scrolling-dependent) and would allow to cache the top/left/width/height values.